# Camera follow with a World Space Canvas gets weird result?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to follow the camera the player along (just the y axis, but this I will look later) for now I have the following problem:
I have a background image in a seperate canvas (World Space) with my Main Camera attached.
Now if I attach a camera follow script (simply `transform.position = Player.transform.position`) the background image follows.
This results to the following: Everything falls down.

I tried to use another camera but I don't know if I just did it wrong. I have no idea.

as I said, just:

```
void update()
{
    transform.position = Player.transform.position
}
```

but the code isn't my problem. I expect that the camera follows the player on the y axis (but not 100% just smoothly a bit) but I will look up for that later
**I want that the Background doesn't move**. Is there another Way to have them background images as a world space, or something I don't know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   void update()
      {transform.position = Player.transform.position}
```

this will make your camera follow your player whatever his direction.

while u didnt mention any details, I expect the reason why everything is falling bec your mainplayer is falling due to physics . and u need to fix this by adding rigibody to your mainplayer and make sure that any thing he walk on also has colliders.

if u want your camera only to follow player on Y axis only , it should be something like this

```
    void update()
          { float y = player.transfor.position.y;
Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(transform.position.x,y,transform.position.z);
transform.position = newPos;
}
```

and I suggest you cach your transform varaibles too.

lastly about your image that you dont want it to move, just dont attach it to any moving gameobject and set it to static and it should never move at all.

Comment: Ah it worked by doing the canvas to world space and give them 2 pictures a rigidbody2d with static. And do you have a idea how i can follow the camera the player on y but not 100%, so just like 50 % follow him? So the movement should be small

Comment: If u want to make a space between camera and canvas,  just add this space to your vector as or subtract it depends on URL need, also if u can add the space and set the canvas as parent to the camera so it follow it automatically without update function